# Java Heap Memory Spikes and Cpu spikes

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, cpu-usage

Atttached is the overview display of my Jconsole

[image: Imgur]

As you can see the Heap Memory Usage Spikes up and the CPU Usage is very spiky as well. However, when the Heap Memory Usage dips(I guess GC happens), the CPU did not spike for a moment.

What could be the possible problem of the Heap Memory increasing, which causes CPU spikes and in-turn, high CPU utilisation.

Comment: By the way, I got this "performance" issue using someone else software. Therefore, I myself do not have code. The thing is how can I be sure that such issue is related to code, or related to GC or even some JVM bug that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

The standard while loop uses around 50% of cpu so it isnt wise having many while loops at once. So what i designed to combat that is a waitBlock that waits a specific amount of time using an inputStream that blocks until there is an inputStream, and so if the waitBlock waits 0001 millisecond then the loop will run 1000 times a second, so although the cpu usage will be basically 0% it has speed limitations. Whith the memory usage from what i understand, if you are using sockets etc. And you dont close sockets and you keep recreating them,the memory usage just builds and builds. Although I might be able to help more if i know what you have done in your code.

Comment: `while` loops? sockets?

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Am I right to say that, there is no way to tell, except looking into the code. 

By the way, I got this "performance" issue using someone else software. Therefore, I myself do not have code.

The thing is how can I be sure that such issue is related to code, or related to GC or even some JVM bug that I'm using.

Comment: Well it seems to be in the code, there must be an odd end that hasn't been accounted for. If you send me the code I can inspect it for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems when a Full GC is performed, the CPU utilisation is normalised.